# Обрезка строки до первого пробела Javascript

Tags: javascript, строки

Помогите пожалуйста, никак не могу разобраться с регулярными выражениями
Есть список ФИО:
(зарнее я не знаю какое ФИО будет)

```js
var a = "Иванов Петр Сергеевич"
var b = "Кириллов Иван Николаевич"
```

Как мне отрезать строку чтобы получить только Имя Отчетсво

```
Петр Сергеевич
Иван Николаевич
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обрезка строки до первого пробела

```js
function getFirstAndMiddleName(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^ ]+ /, '');
}

var a = "Иванов Петр Сергеевич";
var b = "Кириллов Иван Николаевич";
console.log(getFirstAndMiddleName(a));
console.log(getFirstAndMiddleName(b));
```

Способ с нахождением подтроки

```js
function getFirstAndMiddleName(str) {
    return str.match(/[^ ]+ (.+)/)[1];
}
var a = "Иванов Петр Сергеевич";
var b = "Кириллов Иван Николаевич";
console.log(getFirstAndMiddleName(a));
console.log(getFirstAndMiddleName(b));
```

Answer (score 3):

Для этого Вы можете использовать `split`

```js
var a = "Иванов Петр Сергеевич";
var b = "Кириллов Иван Николаевич";
var temp = a.split(" ");
var temp2 = b.split(" ");
var result2 = temp2[1] +" " + temp2[2];
var result = temp[1] +" " + temp[2];
console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```